# Cannot load static JS and CSS files in Django Project with GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm following instructions for a Django app from the link: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

My deployed (flex environment) app is successfully able to run, fetch all static images from the Cloud Storage bucket, however the JS and CSS files won't load. When I right click on my .html files, I can see the links are correct, e.g.:

`<link href='http://storage.googleapis.com/<BUCKET>/static/rest_framework_swagger/css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>`

If I manually paste this link into the browser, it loads the file just fine. Like I said, the static images are accessible but the CSS and JS files are not. Any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the example in the link above is incorrect. It uses `http://` as an example to point to the bucket, whereas it should have been `https://`. Apparently the browser refuses to load the JS and CSS files but is okay with images.

Argh.